# XCode doesn't load a custom view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, swift, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have created a custom view for an error message.

I created an **ErrorView.swift** sub classing `UIView` and I created also an **ErrorView.xib** to use in Interface Builder.

In the identity inspector I set the custom class of the **xib** as **ErrorView.swift** but
when I try to load this specific view it doesn't work.

Why? Can you help me?

This is the code:

My personalized class named `ErrorView`

```
Class ErrorView: UIView {
  class func errorInView(view:UIView, animted:Bool) -> ErrorView {
    println("ERROR VIEW LOADED")
    let errorView = ErrorView(frame: view.bounds)
    errorView.opaque = false
    view.addSubview(errorView)
    return errorView
  }
}
```

my xib:

http://i59.tinypic.com/23tnlev.png

This is the code I use in my `ViewController` to call the view.

```
let errorView = ErrorView.errorInView(self.view, animted: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not loading your xib, instead you are creating a new Error View in code.

If you add `errorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()` after errorView is created, but before you add it as a subview you will see the screen turn green. I have posted this example as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/regnerjr/9e2e33dc358daf47a61a#file-errorview).

If you want to create your view from the xib you will have to load the xib using the normal `NSBundle.mainBundle()` call.

```
let errorView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ErrorView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as ErrorView
```

instead of creating the view with the `ErrorView(frame:)`

This example is also a [gist](https://gist.github.com/regnerjr/b665c856c381cb52c85b#file-errorviewfromxib).